# Magento 1.9 add product to cart only if product is not in the cart

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I'm adding product to the cart but I want to add the product ONLY if the product quantity of this product is 0.  In other words, only add if this product hasn't been added before.  I added this && $qty equal to 0 but that's not working.

Can someone help?

```
if ($item->getData('product_id') == $productId) && $qty == 0) {

     $cart     = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
     $addprod  = 121212;                          
     $qty      = 1;

     $quote  =  Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
         ->addProduct( Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
         ->load($addprod), $qty)->save();
     cart->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$productId = 1;
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
if (! $quote->hasProductId($productId)) {
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    cart->init();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $paramater = array('product' => $productId,
        'qty' => '1'
    );
    $request = new Varien_Object();
    $request->setData($paramater);
    $cart->addProduct($product, $request);
    $cart->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this code to check product exist on cart or not

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$itemsProductIds = $item->getProductId();
if (!in_array($_product->getId(), $itemsProductIds) {
//Code add product to cart
}
```